# Set ConfigureAwait(false) for entire project/dll

Tags: c#, async-await

[According to an article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), it is the best practice to "Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` when you can."  Furthermore it states, "If you can use `ConfigureAwait` at some point within a method, then I recommend you use it for every await in that method after that point."  [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), the author of that article, [states on his blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that "In your *'library'* async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible [emphasis added]."

Given that most or all of my `await` statements in a library project that is meant to be widely used should have `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is it possible to do something/change a setting to make it so that the default behavior of await within my project/dll is to not continue on the a captured context?  That is, so that I could omit all the calls to `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and instead add `.ConfigureAwait(`*`true`*`)` only when I need the context to be preserved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there is no option for this. The Microsoft team did consider a compiler setting or something for that behavior, but ended up rejecting it.

The main reason is that it's quite difficult to tell how the code behaves without knowing how the compiler switch is set.

Comment: It would sure be useful if there was an attribute we could apply to a class or a function that specified the default value of ConfigureAwait.

Comment: Could be be good to test ConfigAwait(false) in any test framework. Any one know's if this kind of functionality exist in any framework.

Comment: @AbdulSaboor: These days there are code analyzers that can force you to always use `ConfigureAwait` (either `true` or `false`), to make it explicit. I personally don't use them, but I can see their benefit, especially on larger teams.

Comment: introducing new keyword (awaitf) was a good idea. I don't understand why .NET does not implement it.

Answer (score 14):

There is now a third party library that supports this.  The [ConfigureAwait.Fody](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ConfigureAwait.Fody) Nuget package allows you to use a `ConfigureAwait` attribute to mark a class, assembly or method such that all awaits should be `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.  The [project page](https://github.com/distantcam/ConfigureAwait) has this example usage:

```
using Fody;

[ConfigureAwait(false)]
public class MyAsyncLibrary
{
    public async Task MyMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        await Task.Delay(20);
    }

    public async Task AnotherMethodAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(30);
    }
}
```

**I have not tried this myself**, but given what I know about how Fody add-ins work, it is certainly possible.

Comment: The ConfigureAwait.Fody is a good idea, but current implementation is buggy and seems  not actively supported

Comment: And because of that, it got unlisted from nuget.

Comment: It was bring back with version 2.0.0 then and 2.1.0 now.